# Problems with session variables in slim php framework

Tags: php, slim

I developed an API that I already have on a server. During the whole development I did tests with POSTMA and I had no problem, however, now that I want to use the API from the production domain to another domain it doesn't work: /

Production -> Local consumption POSTMAN: If it works
Production -> Local consumption from a website: Does not work

The problem is with the session variables, I have some consulates that occupy parameters such as "user ID" or "company id" that I set in the first step when I authenticate with JWT.

Step 1: Authentication (Route)

```
use App\Lib\Auth,
    App\Validation\EmpleadoValidation,
    App\Lib\Response;

$app->group('/autenticar/', function () {
    $this->post('empresa', function ($req, $res, $args) {
      $parametros = $req->getParsedBody();

      if(isset($parametros['API']) && isset($parametros['API-KEY'])){
        return $res->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                ->write(
                  json_encode($this->model->empresaAuth->autenticar($parametros['API'], $parametros['API-KEY']))
                );
      }else{
        $r = new Response;
        return $res->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(403)->write(json_encode($r->SetResponse(false, "Cabeceras no válidas")));
      }

    });

});
```

Step 1.2: Authenticate (Model)

```
public function autenticar($TOKEN, $KEY){
        try{
            $sql="SELECT e.id AS id_empresa, u.id AS id_admin, e.TOKEN, e.KEY,
                    u.email, e.nom_comercial
                    FROM empresas AS e
                    INNER JOIN empresas_usuariosprincipales AS u ON u.id_empresa=e.id
                    WHERE e.TOKEN = :TOKEN AND e.KEY= :KEY and e.API=1";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(":TOKEN", $TOKEN, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":KEY", $KEY, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $respuesta = $stmt ->execute();
            $respuesta = $stmt ->fetch();
            $data = $respuesta;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            die($e);
        }

        if(is_object($data)){
            $token = Auth::SignIn([
                'DISS' => $data->id_empresa.'-'.$data->id_admin,
                'TOKEN' => $data->TOKEN,
            ]);


            /**
             * I used this library but it doesn't work for me
             * https://github.com/akrabat/rka-slim-session-middleware
             */
            $this->sesion->data = $data->TOKEN;
            $this->sesion->id_empresa = $data->id_empresa;
            $this->sesion->id_usuario = $data->id_admin;
            /**
             * I create session variables with the local system, but they don't work either
             */
            $_SESSION['data'] = $data->TOKEN;
            $_SESSION['id_empresa'] = $data->id_empresa;
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $data->id_admin;
            $this->response->data = array("TOKEN" => $token);
            return $this->response->SetResponse(true);
        }else{
            return $this->response->SetResponse("false", "Credenciales no válidas");
        }
    }
```

The problem arises when I want to access some resource of my API, I have a Middelwere configured, I don't know if this is causing the inconvenience. For example, in the following resources, when I access the model, my "user_id" and "business_id" session variables do not exist.

Step 2. I try to access a route (Resource). The resource requests access to the Middelwere

```
$app->group('/agenda/', function () {
      $this->get('get', function ($req, $res, $args) {
        return $res->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                  ->write(
                    json_encode($this->model->agenda->getAll())
                  );
      });
})->add(new AuthMiddlewareEmpresa($app));
```

Step 2.1 The Middleware validates the permissions to access the resource.

```
class AuthMiddlewareEmpresa{
    private $app = null;
    private $r = null;

    public function __construct($app){
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->r = new Response;
    }

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next){
        $c = $this->app->getContainer();
        $app_tokken_name = $c->settings['app_token_name'];

        $token = $request->getHeader($app_tokken_name);
        if($c->model->detallesempresa->obtener()->data!=false && $c->model->detallesempresa->obtener()->data->api==1){
            if(isset($token[0])) $token = $token[0];
            try{
                Auth::Check($token);
            }catch(Exception $e){
                $r = new Response;
                $r->data = array("TOKEN" => null);
                return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(401)->write(json_encode($r->SetResponse(false, "Token no válido.")));

            }
        }else{
            $r = new Response;
            return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(401)->write(json_encode($r->SetResponse(false, "Sin acceso a Jobtify API.")));
        }


        return $next($request, $response);
    }

}
```

**but when the Middleware requires access to the model to validate the permissions from the database. I simply cannot access the session variables. T_T**

2.3. This is the model. Return null because when doing the queries it does not detect the session variables user_id and company_id

```
class DetallesEmpresaModel{
    private $db;
    private $TOKEN = "";
    private $id_empresa = "";
    private $id_usuario = "";
    private $response;
    private $sesion;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->response = new Response();
        $this->sesion = new \RKA\Session();
        if(isset($this->sesion->id_empresa)){
            $this->TOKEN = $_SESSION['data'];
        }
        if(isset($this->sesion->id_empresa)){
            $this->id_empresa = $this->sesion->id_empresa;
        }
        if(isset($this->sesion->id_usuario)){
            $this->id_usuario = $this->sesion->id_usuario;
        }
    }
    /*
        Este modelo es accesible internamente
     */
    public function obtener(){
        try{
            $sql="SELECT e.id_paquete AS paquete, e.activa, e.api, priv.*  FROM empresas_privilegios AS priv
            INNER JOIN empresas AS e ON priv.id_empresa=e.id
            WHERE id_empresa=:id_empresa";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(":id_empresa", $this->id_empresa, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $respuesta = $stmt ->execute();
            $respuesta = $stmt ->fetch();
            $data = $respuesta;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            die($e);
        }

        $this->response->SetResponse(true);
        $this->response->data = $data;
        return $this->response;
    }


}
```